# Why does water in the tube not flow down towards the center of gravity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gravity, atomic-physics, water

[image]

I have a tube that is 1mm wide, and water in it, but seemingly there are parts where air is stuck between the parts where water is. Now 1mm is narrow, but still means millions of water and air molecules. Water molecules are heavier, and should flow to the bottom, just roll down next to the air molecules.

But if the tube is narrow, the air seems to be stuck.

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10955-016-1559-z

I am asking about an explanation at the atomic level.

Question:

1. Why can't water molecules roll down next to the air molecules in the narrow tube?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In small tubes like this, the surface tension forces acting on the water at the air/tube wall/water interface are greater than the gravitational forces. This makes globs of water separated by spaces of air persist in the tube, instead of running together and merging.

As the tube diameter is increased, the radii of curvature at those interfaces goes down and so the relative strength of surface tension forces acting on globs of water goes down compared to gravitational forces. At a critical point, the interface between a glob of water and a slug of air in the tube can deform enough to allow the water and the air to squeeze past one another, the globs merge, and all the water runs to the bottom of the tube and all the air rises to the top.

You can also get the water to merge by reducing its surface tension by adding a little detergent to the water.

Comment: thank you, so the surface tension is acting on the glob of water on the bottom surface of the water too? That is why the water is not coming down? I thought maybe the water (incompressible) being heavier pushes down on the air and since the air is under pressure it somehow won't let water through. But I guess if detergent solves it, than it is just the water. I would like to know what surface tension of the water means in molecules/atoms. Maybe the covalent bonding becomes stronger at the surface.

Comment: there are some good articles on this on wikipedia!

Comment: Surface tension also decreases at increased temperature and at the boiling point the surface tension becomes zero